# How to upscale when exporting to PDF from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf

I need to design a roll-up banner that needs to be 850mm X 2150mm. The printers sent a template that was setup at 20% scale  in size. I designed my lovely banner with the template, exported it as a PDF like they asked and sent it over. They came back saying the size for the banner was wrong... and that it needed to be 850mm X 2150mm. My question is, is there a way of when exporting it to pdf upscaling the document?

I know I can create a new document with those dimensions and just copy everything and scale it to the correct size but then I just don't understand why the printers would sent me a 20% scaled template. Don't they usually upscale the documents when they get them? Since they where the ones that provided the template...

I'm not very experienced with printing "big scale" designs so any help and knowledge would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like there's been some miscommunication between people at your printers... I'd just tell them to send you the correct template or scale the artwork themselves. Sending you a template then (without prior warning) asking you to send artwork at a different scale isn't usual (or reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

How could we know what the printer wanted to tell you? Some printers will indeed produce these using a 1:2 scaled down PDF, but in this case they said something then said something else.

85x215cm is a size InDesign can work with, so save yourself the trouble, re-create this at full size and scale the artwork at 1:1. Send it at full scale.